# Is it safe to do low bar squats with nephroptosis?

Tags: squats

My client has been diagnosed with nephroptosis, and her doctor advised her to do resistance exercises only in lying and seated positions and to strengthen her abdominal muscles - I gave her exercises for all major muscle groups with abdominals included. Before she was diagnosed with the condition, I was walking her through linear progression and because she is quite frail I had her low bar squat around 60℅ to 75℅ of her estimated max for 5 reps, and due to her schedule twice a week. It was not that challenging for her, but anyway I was cautious. She, it seemed, didn't experience and symptoms associated with the condition neither before nor after workouts. I read in this [article](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/319473.php) that intense exercises may be one of the probable causes of this condition, and by implication should be avoided. There is limited data on nephroptosis and resistance training on the internet. I am doubt about whether or not to take the squate out of the program completely or just lower intensity as doctors quite often suggest that weightlifting is not a great idea for people who have conditions. Have you had experience in training people with this condition?

Comment: I'm reluctant to close this initially, as I think there is a good core question here. However, the red flags are the medical condition and the request for experience, which leads to discussions rather than concrete answers. I applaud you for caring about your clients enough to seek help outside your expertise. Honestly what I would recommend is consult with their doctor to construct an appropriate training plan.